# How to include a button within a form that does not act as the Submit button

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4

I have a form that I would like a user to fill out with some basic information.  However, before submitting the info, I want to include a button I am using to activate Stripe to request payment.

I have tried this so far, however, this button before the submission button is acting as the submit button.

Here is some code:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'fans.store')) }}

{{ Form::label('name', 'Name:') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, array(
        'class'     => 'input',
        ));}}

{{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}
{{ Form::text('email', null, array(
        'class'     => 'input',
        ));}}

<div class="button_row">
<button id="customButton" class="button">Purchase</button>
</div>

<div class="button_row">
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'button'])}}
</div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

Any work arounds?  The syntax is blade php (I'm using Laravel 4).  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{{ Form::button('purchase', 'Purchase with Stripe', array( 'id' => 'purchase', 'onclick'=>'myFunction()')) }}
```

That creates a purchase button,

1. labeled "Purchase with Stripe"
2. Calls `myFunction()` that launches stripe

Comment: Can you explain how this would help?  I'm not sure where to use this.  I need the id on purchase button to activate Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button">
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp